# how to define a trigger in a mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

is there any kind of trigger at mongoose model level which provide the capability to set the value of the open field = false when the number of the members collection reaches 100?

```
var mongoose  = require('mongoose');
var Schema    = mongoose.Schema;

var listSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  desc: {
    type: String
  },
  open: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  },
  members: [{
    userid: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'
    },
    prId: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'PR'
    },
    checkedIn: {
      type: Boolean
    }
  }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('List', listSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

Triggers are not available in mongo. It's hard to say why you want to change documents when collection reaches some limit by maybe [capped collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/) is what you really want?

```
new Schema({..}, { capped: { size: 1024, max: 100 } });
```

size is maximum collection size in bytes and max is maximum number of documents that can be inserted in collection.

Comment: a capped collection maybe useful for this situation, but is there any event associate to the collection when reaches the max number of documents? becouse my desire is to change the value of the Open document to false when the capped collection is full

Comment: I don't think there is any. Using capped collection doesn't prevent from inserting more than 100 documents: it is like FIFO queue, when you inserting 101th. document, first one will be removed from collection.